# Enumerating connected subgraphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, enumeration

Is there an efficient algorithm to visit/enumerate all unique connected subgraphs of a labelled graph?

E.g., when the graph is a path, $v_1v_2\dots v_N$, there are $N(N-1)$ unique connected graphs: for any $1\leq i<j\leq N$, the subgraph $v_i\dots v_j$. For graphs with denser edge structure, the number of unique connected subgraphs can be as high as $2^{|V|}$ (for cliques).

Fortunately, graphs I'm interested in have a lot of articulation points, so the total number of unique connected subsets should be polynomial in the size of the input.

For those who are interested, I'm modeling a problem in protein mass-spectrometry. Starting from a protein (chain of amino acids, with occasional long-distance bonds due to disulphide bonds), I'd like to generate a database of all possible sub-species that may result from breaks in peptide and/or disulphide bonds.

Comment: Well, in general the answer is *no*, as you observed (cliques have $2^n$ connected subgraphs). So somehow I feel like you should describe your special structure more. Indeed, why can't you just brute-force if you know the number is polynomial in the size of the graph?

Comment: Looks like this question already has an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658245/efficiently-find-all-connected-subgraphs)

Comment: As written, the question is unanswerable, since you've already observed that the answer depends crucially on the class of graphs under consideration and you haven't told us what the class is. Also, there are a couple of little inconsistencies: when you describe subgraphs of the path, you exclude one-vertex graphs but, when you describe subgraphs of the clique, you include them and even the 0-vertex graph. Also, claiming that there are $2^{|V|}$ subgraphs of the clique suggests you mean *induced* subgraphs but you don't say this explicitly. A clique has many more non-induced subgraphs.

Comment: @Arthur Well, coding down brute-force approaches would not be considered an answer here, I think. Anyway, please don't crosspost like this!

Comment: In this case, "efficient" can be reasonably defined as an output-sensitive algorithm: e.g., running time is linear (or polynomial) in the number of unique connected subgraphs.  Looks like there was an algorithm posted two years ago on SO, per the comment, but it's not clear whether the running time of that algorithm achieves good output-sensitive behavior: all that is claimed is that its running time is $O(2^n)$, which is not what this question asks for.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [enumerating all connected induced subgraphs](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/16305/5038) (on TCS.SE), there is an algorithm whose running time is polynomial in the number of connected subgraphs.  Therefore, if you know that the number of connected subgraphs is polynomial in the input size, there is an algorithm that is polynomial in the size of the input.  The polynomial might be fairly high degree, so I don't know whether the algorithm will be efficient in practice, but you could try it out and see.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/15658245/781723.